# User based deploying in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am slightly newbie on kubernetes. And we want the present some of our products as SaaS to our costumers. So i need the user based isolated deployments. After some research i decided to create a namespace to each user. Then deploy what user wants from our template to user's namespace. But there is a problem about port mapping. Lets say we have 6 user and all of them want's the deploy django app. So all of them wants to access their project from 80 and 443 ports. Is there any solution for this in kubernetes? If it is how should i proceed?

And how can i seperate each users deployments to diffrent networks or vlans to isolate their networks from each other?

Comment: How much do you trust your customers? Kubernetes security is not really something I would want to use for this if there is a risk of an adversary getting in as a customer. Kubernetes permissions and namespaces and all that are not built to be hard security boundaries.

Comment: why you don't use ingress rules and services. So each user will have his rule pointing to the required service and the service will point to the correct deployment. Like this users are totally separated and will not affect each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put a dedicated load balancer to each of them (the expensive solution, but straight forward), or make your Ingress Controller to only accept requests with a hostname, and point each hostname to it's service, in its namespace (cheap solution but complicate).

**Load Balancer Solution:**

This one is easy, if you are with a cloud provider, so every time a client exposes the app, you just create a `LoadBalancer` type service pointing to his app. Since for each app you get a new load balancer, you have no problem of port collision. Now, the drawbacks are that this you can do only with a cloud provider, and it will be quite expensive.

**Ingress Solution:**

This one is the pro solution. It's cheap, but it's also more complex. So, you would create an Ingress resource like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls 
  rules:
  - host: site1.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path1/
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
  - host: site2.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
    ...
```

Here, you just have one L7 load balancer, and that's Ingress Controller doing all the routing. Depending on Ingress Controller, you might get an L4 load balancer (e.g. nginx, Traefik), but still that's Ingres Controller doing the routing.

Complexity? You will have to figure out a way to update the Ingress Controller records without a downtime for other users. Also, on Kubernetes, an Ingress Controller can't pass a request from one namespace to another. So, the service needs to run in the same namespace that the `Ingress` resource has been created (Note, I'm saying `Ingress` resource, being the rules (like the yaml above); not Ingress Controller). This is a known limitation that Kubernetes team already announced that will never be changed, as it introduces a huge security hole.

You will need to create headless services without selectors in the same namespace that `Ingress` object, and separately create `Endpoint` objects pointing to the service in the other namespaces. It might look like cumbersome, but that's quite pro actually.

Answer (score 1):

To separate external access to the apps you need to deploy an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) and create different Ingresses pointing to Services of each application. Every Ingress will hold its unique URL per application.

To prohibit internal cross-namespace communication you need to deploy [network policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). Fr this you'll need to deploy an [addon](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/).
Or you can solve it by deploying any common service mesh: Istio, Linkerd, Consul etc.